# jar file load html pages in JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, jar, executable-jar

I'm trying to load html pages stored inside the jar file into a help JEditorPane. So far it works when I run it in eclipse but when i make a runnable jar it wont work, except if i put the map res/pages/... in the same map with the jar file

```
class HelpButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
             infodex = new JEditorPane();
                helpDialog = new JDialog();


            URL url1 = null;
            try {
                url1 = (new java.io.File("res/pages/help.html")).toURI().toURL();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            try {
                infodex.setPage(url1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            helpDialog.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(infodex));
            helpDialog.setBounds(400,200,700,600);
            helpDialog.show();
            infodex.setEditable(false);
            Hyperactive hyper = new Hyperactive();
            infodex.addHyperlinkListener(hyper);


        }


    }
```

Comment: See also [tag:embedded-resource] [info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A file packaged inside a .jar is not a file on the file system.  You cannot access it with the File class.

A file inside a .jar is called an application resource.  You access it using the [Class.getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) method:

```
url1 = HelpButtonHandler.class.getResource("/res/pages/help.html");
```

It is up to you to make sure the files are properly packaged in your .jar.  If `url1` is null, check the structure of your .jar file.

Answer (score 1):

When you put resources in a jar, you cannot access them using `File`.  You need to access them as a resource through the (more precisely: *a*) classloader.  For example:

```
HelpButtonHandler.class.getResource("/res/pages/help.html");
```

Make sure you put the resource in the right place: if you leave out the first slash ('`/`'), the classloader will try to locate it relative to your class (which is usually not what you want).

Answer (score 0):

use gerResource() method...

```
url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("res/pages/help.html");
```

check this link

http://oakgreen.blogspot.com/2011/12/java-getclassgetclassloadergetresourcem.html